# Name and author number changes in unsrnat.bst not reflecting in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, custom-bib, abbrvnat.bst

I am working on customising the `unsrnat.bst` file as per my requirements. I have already edited it to remove the url and doi. This works well.
After checking different posts in the forum, I also edited the code to have the first and the middle name initials and the full last name. But, this change to the author name does not reflect in the bibliography.

```
{ s nameptr "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
```

Secondly, abbreviations are shown in lowercase, whereas I would like to have them in uppercase. I also changed the code to specify the number of authors after which `et al` should be used. But even this does not reflect in the bibliogrpahy.

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
        nameptr #3
        #1 + =
        numnames #5
        > and
        { "others" 't :=
        #1 'namesleft := }
        'skip$
        if$
        namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                { " et~al." * }
                { " and " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

Can someone please help me with this?
Here is the link to the customised `bst` file: https://ufile.io/nvov3

At present the a biblipgraphic entry looks like this:

> Norris, Jeremy L and Cornett, Dale S and Mobley, James A and
>   Andersson, Malin and Seeley, Erin H and Chaurand, Pierre and Caprioli,
>   Richard M. Processing maldi mass spectra to improve mass spectral
>   direct tissue analysis. Int J Mass Spectrom, 260(2):212{221, 2007.

Within this, only the initials of the first name should be visible and abbreviation like "maldi" should be in uppercase.

Here is the corresponding bib entry:

```
@Article{norris07processing,
  author =    {Norris, Jeremy L and Cornett, Dale S and Mobley, James A and Andersson, Malin and Seeley, Erin H and Chaurand, Pierre and Caprioli, Richard M},
  title =     {Processing MALDI mass spectra to improve mass spectral direct tissue analysis},
  journal =   {Int J Mass Spectrom},
  year =      {2007},
  volume =    {260},
  number =    {2},
  pages =     {212--221},
  abstract =  {Profiling and imaging biological specimens using MALDI mass spectrometry has significant potential to contribute to our understanding and diagnosis of disease. The technique is efficient and high-throughput providing a wealth of data about the biological state of the sample from a very simple and direct experiment. However, in order for these techniques to be put to use for clinical purposes, the approaches used to process and analyze the data must improve. This study examines some of the existing tools to baseline subtract, normalize, align, and remove spectral noise for MALDI data, comparing the advantages of each. A preferred workflow is presented that can be easily implemented for data in ASCII format. The advantages of using such an approach are discussed for both molecular profiling and imaging mass spectrometry.},
  doi =       {10.1016/j.ijms.2006.10.005},
  file =      {NorrisEtAl_ProcessingMALDIMassSpectraDirectTissueAnalysis_IJMS_2007.pdf:2007/NorrisEtAl_ProcessingMALDIMassSpectraDirectTissueAnalysis_IJMS_2007.pdf:PDF},
  keywords =  {Profiling; Imaging; Mass spectrometry; MALDI; Pre-processing},
  owner =     {adm},
  publisher = {Elsevier},
  timestamp = {2015.01.07}
}
```

I would also like to separate author names by comma rather than "and".

Comment: Please add the bib entry to your question ...